# Zend Framework 2 (MimePart) Message headers encoded with “=?utf-8?Q?"

Tags: php, zend-framework2, smtp, mime

If I send Mail from my local server in message source I see it:

```
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

But, if I send Mail from another server, message source looks like this:

```
Content-Type: =?utf-8?Q?text/html?=
Content-Transfer-Encoding: =?utf-8?Q?8bit?=
```

My ZF2 application is identical in both servers. I send mail using zf2 SMTP transport class.
Local server running under Ubuntu 13.10 + Apache, another server under Ubuntu 13.04 + Nginx

Why message sources are not identical?

Comment: how are you setting the header? Are you using Zend\Mime\Part and Zend\Mime\Message? Or are you just hardcode the encoding?

Comment: I setting content type header using `Zend/Mime/MimePart`
`$htmlPart = new MimePart($html);
$htmlPart->type = 'text/html';` and set it to `Zend/Mail/Message`

Comment: After `$message = new Message();` try explicitly setting the encoding as `$message->setEncoding('UTF-8');`. May be now both the message sources would be identical.

Comment: yes, I set the encoding, this line is in my code..